# php_pdo не подключается

Tags: php_pdo, настройка, php

Стоит Денвер (php 5.3.3). Пытаюсь подключить `sqlite`.

```
php_pdo.dll
php_sqlite.dll
```

присутствуют в папке с расширениями.

Иду в `php.ini`, раскомментариваю строки

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll
```

Но тут моему удивлению нет предела - сначала вылазит ошибка

> "Точка входа в процедуру php_set_error_handling не найдена в библиотеке DDL php5ts.dll"

Потом опять иду в php.ini и строка

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
```

оказывается закомментареной.

Как с этим бороться? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась переустановкой php. Хотя по-прежнему непонятно, почему переписывался конфиг...

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить путь к php в %PATH%, в php.ini в параметре extension_dir = указать полный путь, и раскомментировать библиотеку в три часа ночи. Еще возможно ваш файл автогенерируется, скорее всего настройки в денвере надо менять в другом месте.